# Display success message within a div

Tags: php, forms

I got this peace of code on the page that handles the submitted data from a form on page 1. Using *sprintf* to display a success message on Page 1. As for now, the success message displays on top of page 1. How do I display the success message within a div that I have on page 1.

```
$params = array(
            ':restrict' => $this->options['restricted'],
            ':name'     => $this->options['name'],
            ':email'    => $this->options['email'],
            ':level'    => $this->options['user_level'],
            ':id'       => $this->id
        );
        $sql = "UPDATE `login_users` SET `restricted` = :restrict, `name` = :name, `email` = :email, `user_level` = :level WHERE `user_id` = :id;";
        parent::query($sql, $params);
        $result = sprintf("<div class='alert alert-success'>"._('User information updated for')." <b>%s</b> (%s).</div>",$this->options['name'], $this->options['username']);
```

Comment: save your message in the $result, on the page 1 make a div and echo the result in taht div
<div class='alert alert-success'><?php echo $result ; ?> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use jquery or
you have to use this statement where you want to display this message

```
$result = sprintf("<div class='alert alert-success'>"._('User information updated for')." <b>%s</b> (%s).</div>",$this->options['name'], $this->options['username']);
```